# Why does 5/10 = 0.0?

Tags: c#, double

Curious as to why

```
double progress = 5/10;
```

show's that my variable `progress` = 0.0 when it should equal 0.5, right?

Explicitly defining `progress` as

```
double progress = 0.5;
```

Works correctly, but I need to define this mathematically not explicitly. Maybe I'm missing a lib or something, or my brain. Vis Studio 2012 Win 7 x64.

Comment: integer division

Comment: Is it a const or a var?

Comment: yeah try (double)5/(double)10

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because you are doing integer division. Try `5.0/10.0` instead. (Or `5.0/10` or `5/10.0` - at least one of the operands being a `double`.)

The compiler doesn't use the stuff to the left of the `=` sign to determine the value of the constant expression on the right. It interpets the `5` as an *integer* and the `10` as an *integer* and thus the `/` as *integer division*.

When you add a decimal point to a literal number, it is interpreted as a `double`. When division is done between a `double` and an `int`, the `int` will be converted to a `double` and "regular" division will be used.

Note that `(double)(5/10)` will give you the `double` `0` - ***not*** `double` `0.5`. This is for the same reasons as described above: the constant expression integer division `5/10` is interpreted free of any context external to that expression.

Comment: Or even just 5.0/10. As long as one of the values is a double, the whole expression will be evaluated as such.

Comment: 5/10f works as well

Answer (score 3):

You're dividing two `int`-s so the result is an `int` that's finally assigned to the `double`. Since an `int` can't represent fractions, it's rounded down. The operation is an integer division because all terms are integers.

If you do `5.0 / 10.0`, you'll get the right result.

Answer (score 3):

the expression `5/10` is an integral expression and so uses integral math.  Define one or both of the operands as a double to get double math:

```
double progress = 5.0 / 10.0;
```